# how to subtract values in consecutive rows?

Tags: sql-server

I have following table with some data.

```
CREATE TABLE #NetProfit (ID int, [Name] varchar(50),[Class] varchar(50), Balance money)
 go
 --Populate Sample records
 INSERT INTO #NetProfit VALUES(4,'Income','No Class',303386.8462)
 INSERT INTO #NetProfit VALUES(6,'Expenses','No Class',22443.5317)
 INSERT INTO #NetProfit VALUES(4,'Income','2 TestUser3',0.00)
 INSERT INTO #NetProfit VALUES(5,'Cost','2 TestUser3',0.3875)
 INSERT INTO #NetProfit VALUES(6,'Expenses','2 TestUser3',6439.2129)
 INSERT INTO #NetProfit VALUES(5,'Cost','3 TestUser3',0.1395)
 INSERT INTO #NetProfit VALUES(6,'Expenses','3 TestUser3',6451.6129)
 INSERT INTO #NetProfit VALUES(5,'Cost','38 Code#1012',3.0225)
 INSERT INTO #NetProfit VALUES(6,'Expenses','38 Code#1012',30.225) 
 go
 select * from #NetProfit
 drop table #NetProfit

+----+----------+--------------+-------------+
| ID |   Name   |    Class     |   Balance   |
+----+----------+--------------+-------------+
|  4 | Income   | No Class     | 303386.8462 |
|  6 | Expenses | No Class     | 22443.5317  |
|  4 | Income   | 2 TestUser3  | 0           |
|  5 | Cost     | 2 TestUser3  | 0.3875      |
|  6 | Expenses | 2 TestUser3  | 6439.2129   |
|  5 | Cost     | 3 TestUser3  | 0.1395      |
|  6 | Expenses | 3 TestUser3  | 6451.6129   |
|  5 | Cost     | 38 Code#1012 | 3.0225      |
|  6 | Expenses | 38 Code#1012 | 30.225      |
+----+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

I want to subtract [Balance] column row wise group by [Class] column.
For ex. NetProfit = (Income - Cost - Expenses) for each [Class] column with group by [Class].

Here is the output I am expecting.

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|  No Class   | 2 TestUser3 | 3 TestUser3 | 38 Code#1012 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| 280943.3145 | 6439.6004   | 6451.7524   | 33.2475      |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the first step to achieve desired result:

```
SELECT NP.Class, ABS(ISNULL(SUM(CASE NP.Name WHEN 'Income' THEN NP.Balance END), 0) - SUM(CASE NP.Name WHEN 'Income' THEN NULL ELSE NP.Balance END)) AS Balance
FROM #NetProfit AS NP
GROUP BY NP.Class;
```

Then you would have to dynamically pivot these results. Statically, your query should look like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT NP.Class, ABS(ISNULL(SUM(CASE NP.Name WHEN 'Income' THEN NP.Balance END), 0) - SUM(CASE NP.Name WHEN 'Income' THEN NULL ELSE NP.Balance END)) AS Balance
    FROM #NetProfit AS NP
    GROUP BY NP.Class) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT (MAX(Balance) FOR Class IN ([2 TestUser3], [3 TestUser3], [38 Code#1012], [No Class])) AS PivotTable;
```

So by plugging in dynamic SQL, This is the result:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Col NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Col = STUFF((   SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(NP.Class)
                     FROM #NetProfit AS NP
                     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SET @SQL = N'
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT NP.Class, ABS(ISNULL(SUM(CASE NP.Name WHEN ''Income'' THEN NP.Balance END), 0) - SUM(CASE NP.Name WHEN ''Income'' THEN NULL ELSE NP.Balance END)) AS Balance
    FROM #NetProfit AS NP
    GROUP BY NP.Class) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT (MAX(Balance) FOR Class IN (' + @Col + N')) AS PivotTable';

EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

That's the output:

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2 TestUser3 | 3 TestUser3 | 38 Code#1012 |  No Class   |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| 6439,6004   | 6451,7524   | 33,2475      | 280943,3145 |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL old hat.

Comment: There's no other proven way to do that. :)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Thank you so much for your response. It is working according to my need. Really appreciated. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

This query return calculation in rows.
With pivot table you can turn rows to columns

```
select isnull(c1, c2), isnull(i, 0)-isnull(e,0) from (
 select * from 
 (select class c1, sum(balance) i
 from #NetProfit
 where Name = 'income'
 group by class) i
 full join
 (
 select class c2, sum(balance) e
 from #NetProfit
 where Name != 'income'
 group by class) e  on i.c1 = e.c2) t
```